# Mostrar datos guardados en Sqlite

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Como mostrar en un Text view los datos almacenados en la base Sqlite presionando el botón,ya que con el actual codigo al presionar el botón me sale EnsayoNull.

Este es el codigo :

```
       package com.example.mand.crudsqliteandroid;


       import android.database.Cursor;
       import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.TextView;
       import BSHELPER.Usuarios;
       import BSHELPER.sqlite;


public class prueba2 extends AppCompatActivity{

    private TextView mitexto;
    private Button miBoton;
    private Usuarios usuarios;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba2);


            mitexto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            miBoton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

            miBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    mitexto.setText("Ensayo"+usuarios);

                }

            });
        }

        public Usuarios recuperar (int idusuario) {

        sqlite bh  = new sqlite(prueba2.this,"usuarios",null,1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = bh.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] valores_recuperar = {"idusuario", "nombre", "edad", "apellidos"};

        Cursor c = db.query("usuarios", valores_recuperar, "_id=" + idusuario,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Usuarios usuarios = new Usuarios(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1),
                c.getString(2), c.getInt(2));

        db.close();
        c.close();

       return usuarios;

       }

    }

package BSHELPER;

public class Usuarios {

    private int idusuario,edad;
    private String nombre,apellidos;

    public Usuarios(int idusuario,String nombre,String apellidos,int edad){
        setIdusuario(idusuario);
        setNombre(nombre);
        setApellidos(apellidos);
        setEdad(edad);
    }

    public int getIdusuario() {
        return idusuario;
    }

    public void setIdusuario(int idusuario) {
        this.idusuario = idusuario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

}


package BSHELPER;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public String usuarios = "CREATE TABLE usuarios(idusuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,nombre TEXT,apellidos TEXT," +
            "edad INTEGER)";
    public sqlite(Context context,String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,int version){
        super(context,name,factory,version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(usuarios);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Comment: o hay algún otro metodo?

Comment: alguien que me ayude por favorrrr